# Почему SmtpClient не отправляет письмо и не выдает исключение?

Tags: c#, wpf, email, mail.ru

При запуске данного кода:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(senderBox.Text);
mail.To.Add(recipientBox.Text);
mail.Subject = subjectBox.Text;
mail.Body = bodyBox.Text;

SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
SmtpServer.Port = 465;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderBox.Text, passwordBox.Password);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

try
{
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

Код покидает функцию после строки `SmtpServer.Send(mail);`, но письмо не отправляется и код не входит в catch-блок. Чем можно объяснить такое поведение?
UPD:
проблема была в порте.Попробовал 587-все нормально работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для диагностики, чтобы понять что происходит, можно включить следующий блок в раздел `<configuration>` в файл app.config

Тогда можно будет увидеть и понять отправилось Ваше сообщение на smtp сервер или нет и что именно происходит.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="MyTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 7):

SMTP сервер mail.ru не смотря на то что работает через SSL но при этом использует 25 порт, вот такой вот парадокс, потратил пол-дня пока разобрался

Comment: у топикастера и так написано "SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true"

Comment: @PashaPash совершенно верно, но порт при этом надо указать 25, при этом у них в инструкциях везде указан 465 порт, и я потратил кучу времени, прежде чем с психу 25 порт не прописал :)

Comment: Да, у меня на 465-ом порту просто по таймауту отваливается. А в диагностическом файле видно как System.Net выдает ошибку вида '**System.Net Error: 0 : [6668] Exception in SmtpClient#2479830::Send - Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall..**'
 А через 25-й уходит нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `Send` не гарантирует 100% отправки сообщения. Этот метод только добавляет ваше письмо в очередь на отправку на `SMTP` сервере, а дальше уже сервер сам решает отправлять его или нет. Проверьте сервер. На том же `mail.ru` стоят фильтры антиспама - проверьте, что письмо не попало в них. Если ничего не выйдет - напишите в саппорт или смените `SMTP` сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой работающий код (ранее тоже мучался с этим вопросом)

```
     private Task SendEmailAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        string email_address = "blala@blala.ru";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email_address, "blala");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Timeout = 20000; //20s

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(email_address, message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);

        try
        {
            //smtp.SendAsync(mailMessage, 1);
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Произошла ошибка при отправке email: {ex.Message}");
            Task.FromException(ex);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);

    }
```

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/329477)

Comment: Поправил свой ответ