# Ошибка при запросе на подключение

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core

Есть скрипт для отправки сообщения на почту:

```
 public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("BeletExport Administration", "ITCyborg2001@yandex.ru"));
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email));
            emailMessage.Subject = subject;
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = message
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (mysender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("*****@mail.ru", "*****");
                await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mail.ru", 465, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при отправке почты" + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Использую MailKit.
Появляется ошибка **"Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение [::ffff:93.158.134.38]:465"**.
Пробовал подключаться с других браузеров, результат не изменился. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что  нет почтового сервера по указанному IP  и порту

Comment: Я ведь смотрел. 465 - порт для smtp (SSL). И что означает "на той стороне"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему SmtpClient не отправляет письмо и не выдает исключение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466328/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-smtpclient-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)